# Filter geoJSON layer after it has been loaded

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, filter

I'm declaring and defining a geoJSON layer first, like:

```
var layer1 = L.geoJson(null, {
   onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
   ...
   }
});
```

..and then loading a CSV into it, like:

```
omnivore.csv('pbstatus.csv', null, layer1 )
   .on('ready', function(e) {
       ...
});
```

Now, I want to create other geoJSON layers as subsets of `layer1` based on the value of one of the CSV's columns loaded into the layer's feature.properties dataset. Is there a way to filter `layer1` AFTER it's been defined and loaded? I'm aware of the 'proper' way of filtering when defining the layer:

```
var layer1 = L.geoJson(null, {
   onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
   ...
   },
   filter: function(feature, layer) {
   return (feature.properties.foo == 'bar');
   }
});
```

.. but I don't want to repetitively do a different declaration each time. And, the data in the CSV is going to decide which layers and how many to form; we may not know all the possible filter conditions before we have imported the CSV. Is there a way I can spawn new layers as subsets of this `layer1` after it's been loaded with geoJSON data ? Would the new layers also inherit the properties, actions and behaviours set in `layer1`'s `onEachFeature:` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just came across this again and realised I hadn't updated that I found an answer.

I initiated empty layers beforehand:

```
var statusComplete = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);     layerControl.addOverlay(statusComplete, 'Complete');
var statusProgress = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);     layerControl.addOverlay(statusProgress, 'Work in Progress');
var statusUnfinished = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);   layerControl.addOverlay(statusUnfinished, 'Left Unfinished');
var statusNotstarted = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);   layerControl.addOverlay(statusNotstarted, 'Work not Started');
var statusUnsure = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);       layerControl.addOverlay(statusUnsure, 'Unsure');
```

Inside the onEachFeature function, I added `layer.addTo()` statements.

```
var statusLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
   onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
   ...
    var statusCheck = feature.properties['Actual Status'].toLowerCase();
    if( statusCheck == 'complete' ) layer.addTo(statusComplete);
    else if( statusCheck == 'work in progress' ) layer.addTo(statusProgress);
    else if( statusCheck == 'left unfinished' ) layer.addTo(statusUnfinished);
    else if( statusCheck == 'work not started' ) layer.addTo(statusNotstarted);
    else layer.addTo(statusUnsure);

}
```

The features added to the other layers carried on whatever I defined for them in this "mother" layer : marker icons, popups, tooltips. This was useful; I did not have to repeat the same lines of code again for five different layers.

And though the CSV itself was loaded (via `omnivore`) into the "mother" layer, I never actually added it to either the `map` or the `layerControl`. It stayed invisible, while the new layers `statusComplete, statusProgress, statusUnfinished, statusNotstarted, statusUnsure` were added to the map.

You may see the [full code here](https://github.com/answerquest/answerquest.github.io/blob/master/janwani-pbstatus.zip).

PS: I'm not really sure why I initiated the child layers as `L.layerGroup()`, and not sure how else to initiate them.